# Do I need additional VirtualHost entries for 443 when using Let's Encrypt?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, virtualhost, lets-encrypt

I'm pretty new to putting SSL in on my websites, which I host in AWS in an EC2 running a simple LAMP stack. I don't handle any data that necessarily needs to be encrypted, and am really only instituting SSL because of "best practices" and most browsers disliking insecure connections these days.

I figured Let's Encrypt would be the easiest, cost-effective way to do this (as opposed to using ACM, which sounds expensive). I got Certbot installed and the wizard appears to have run successfully. It forces all HTTP connections over to the HTTPS side when loading my domains. It clearly updated my VirtualHosts code with the RewriteCond stuff to do so, however, my VirtualHost is still only listening on *:80.

Do I need to duplicate this code with a *:443? I don't think I even put a Listen 443 in my main httpd.conf, unless LE added it. I'm just a bit confused on how my SSL connections are apparently working, when the only thing I've done with port 443 thus far is open my Security Groups for it.

Answer (score 0):

It shows up in /etc/httpd/conf.d/hosts-le-ssl.conf.

That's what I get for not looking at the output!